# Horizontally-scrolling div inside a flex column

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't seem to have a horizontally-scrolling div inside a flex column.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/aximili/pen/jObWOaa)

```css
.container { display: flex; margin: 20px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid blue; }
.side-nav { flex-shrink: 0; width: 100px; min-height: 100%; background: grey; }
.main { padding: 20px; }

.scrollable { overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%; }
.long-content { width: 2000px; height: 50px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='side-nav'>
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    
    <div class='scrollable'>
      <div class='long-content'>
        This is supposed to scroll horizontally unless your window is super wide
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <p>Some paragraph below the scrollable box</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I change the `max-width` of `.scrollable` to `px` it would work, but I need it to fill the column.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a Module"bug" (Wierd).
Anyway, one very simple solution is to use `flex-basis` (Instead of `width`).

Step 1 for `main` add `width: 0`;

```css
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  margin: 20px; 
  height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}
.side-nav { flex-shrink: 0; width: 100px; min-height: 100%; background: grey; }
.main { 
  padding: 20px; 
  border: 5px dashed orange; 
  /* "new code" */
  width: 0px;
}

.scrollable { overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%; }
.long-content { width: 2000px; height: 50px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <aside class='side-nav'>
    Aside
  </aside>
  <main class='main'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class='scrollable'>
      <div class='long-content'>
        This is supposed to scroll horizontally unless your window is super wide
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <p>Some paragraph below the scrollable box</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Step 2 - `main` add `flex-basis: 100%`;

```css
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  margin: 20px; 
  height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}
.side-nav { flex-shrink: 0; width: 100px; min-height: 100%; background: grey; }
.main { 
  padding: 20px; 
  border: 5px dashed orange; 
  /* "new code" */
  width: 0px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.scrollable { overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%; }
.long-content { width: 2000px; height: 50px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <aside class='side-nav'>
    Aside
  </aside>
  <main class='main'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class='scrollable'>
      <div class='long-content'>
        This is supposed to scroll horizontally unless your window is super wide
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Some paragraph below the scrollable box</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

One more option is to use `width: 0;` & `flex-grow:1`

```css
.container { 
  display: flex; 
  margin: 20px; 
  height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}
.side-nav { flex-shrink: 0; width: 100px; min-height: 100%; background: grey; }
.main { 
  padding: 20px; 
  border: 5px dashed orange; 
  /* "new code" */
  width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scrollable { overflow-x: auto; max-width: 100%; }
.long-content { width: 2000px; height: 50px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <aside class='side-nav'>
    Aside
  </aside>
  <main class='main'>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class='scrollable'>
      <div class='long-content'>
        This is supposed to scroll horizontally unless your window is super wide
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Some paragraph below the scrollable box</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

I don't like any of those ideas - but this is life hh.

Comment: `width: 0` works like a charm. I thought about `flex-grow: 1` but without `width: 0`, it doesn't work.